# Showing that 3-colorable is NP-complete

Tags: graphs, np-complete, reductions, colorings, clique

Just as a background, *3-colorable* problem is as follows: Given a graph $G = (V, E)$, is it possible to color the vertices using just 3 colors such that no neighboring vertices have the same color?

I'm aware we can show that *3-colorable* is an NP-complete problem by reducing *3-SAT* to it. But I'm wondering is it possible to reduce *clique* to it?

I know for example that if a graph with n vertices contains a subgraph which is a clique of size k, then you need at least k colors (that is, the chromatic number is at least k).

So could we say that if a graph contains a *clique* of size 4, then it is not *3-colorable*, and vice versa?

Edit: Hmm..upon further thought, maybe the reduction wouldn't work because in order to reduce clique, you can't fix ahead of time that you're looking for a clique of size 4? The size of the clique would be arbitrary..

Comment: What have you tried?  Have you tried looking for a proof of your claim?  Have you tried looking for a counterexample?  Try some small graphs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A problem $P$ being NP-hard means that all problems in NP can be reduced to $P$. That's by definition. Working out the exact reduction needed can be  tricky, which is why one usually looks for a somehow similar problem to prove hardness. You probably wouldn't try to directly reduce [MINIMUM INTERVAL GRAPH COMPLETION](http://www.nada.kth.se/~viggo/wwwcompendium/node50.html) to [Tetris](http://arxiv.org/pdf/cs/0210020v1.pdf) to prove its hardness.

In general you can chain reductions. In your case, since you know 3-colorability can be used to solve 3-SAT and you know 3-SAT can be used to solve CLIQUE, you can first transform your CLIQUE instance to 3-SAT and then the resulting formula to a 3-colourability problem.

Answer (score 5):

No, you couldn't say that, because it's not true.

A helpful method is to *prove* all your claims.  Don't just guess -- try to find a proof.  If you're struggling to find a proof, the first thing to check is whether maybe the thing you're trying to prove is false, so look for a counterexample.  In this case you should easily be able to find a counterexample to your claim.  Alternatively, if you can't find a proof and can't find a counterexample, look for a different approach or a different way to solve the problem that uses only facts you do know how to prove correct.